# Remove Â from output

Tags: php, mysql

How can I remove weird `Â` characters from my output without needing to edit hundreds of rows in MySQL.

Data is being read from a MySQL database and outputted to the browser via HTML.

Comment: What is present instead of `Â` in real data?

Comment: Looking at the row in MySQL it seems like multiple spaces at the back of the string, but `trim()` doesn't remove them.

Comment: When in doubt, `echo bin2hex($row['col'])`, then figure out from the hex dump and your favourite ASCII/Unicode table what those mysterious characters are.